# Why object files are not linking with the allegro library even when using -L and -I commands?

Tags: c++

I'm using vs code and trying to link with allegro. I've little knowledge about .json files so i avoid them. This is the sample code i'm trying to run:

```
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_font.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    al_init();
    al_init_font_addon();
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY* display = al_create_display(800, 600);
    ALLEGRO_FONT* font = al_create_builtin_font();
    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0, 0, 0));
    al_draw_text(font, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), 400, 300, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_CENTER, "Welcome to Allegro!");
    al_flip_display();
    al_rest(5.0);
    al_destroy_font(font);
    al_destroy_display(display);
    return 0;
}
```

by using the cmd command:

```
g++ -o test.exe main.cpp -IE:\ImportantSoftwares\allegro\include -LE:\ImportantSoftwares\allegro\lib -lallegro_monolith
```

Im getting following error:

```
C:\Users\SHAO~1\AppData\Local\Temp/cccXEAJj.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `al_install_system'
C:\Users\SHAO~1\AppData\Local\Temp/cccXEAJj.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x3f): undefined reference to `al_init_font_addon'
C:\Users\SHAO~1\AppData\Local\Temp/cccXEAJj.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x53): undefined reference to `al_create_display'
C:\Users\SHAO~1\AppData\Local\Temp/cccXEAJj.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x5b): undefined reference to `al_create_builtin_font'
C:\Users\SHAO~1\AppData\Local\Temp/cccXEAJj.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x81): undefined reference to `al_map_rgb'
C:\Users\SHAO~1\AppData\Local\Temp/cccXEAJj.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `al_clear_to_color'
C:\Users\SHAO~1\AppData\Local\Temp/cccXEAJj.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xc7): undefined reference to `al_map_rgb'
C:\Users\SHAO~1\AppData\Local\Temp/cccXEAJj.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x113): undefined reference to `al_draw_text'
C:\Users\SHAO~1\AppData\Local\Temp/cccXEAJj.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x118): undefined reference to `al_flip_display'
C:\Users\SHAO~1\AppData\Local\Temp/cccXEAJj.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x126): undefined reference to `al_rest'
C:\Users\SHAO~1\AppData\Local\Temp/cccXEAJj.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x131): undefined reference to `al_destroy_font'
C:\Users\SHAO~1\AppData\Local\Temp/cccXEAJj.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x13c): undefined reference to `al_destroy_display'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have also tried to link allegro with codeblocks step by step described in this video:
https://youtu.be/xH8mpOfRGxE

But im getting same error

EDIT:

I've changed above command to:

```
g++ main.cpp -o test.exe -IE:/ImportantSoftwares/allegro/include -LE:/ImportantSoftwares/allegro/lib -lallegro_monolith-debug.dll -lallegro_monolith.dll
```

i've also tried removing .dll in above command like:

```
g++ main.cpp -o test.exe -IE:/ImportantSoftwares/allegro/include -LE:/ImportantSoftwares/allegro/lib -lallegro_monolith-debug -lallegro_monolith
```

but im getting same error

Comment: Are you on Windows? You might try to use forward slashes in your paths.

Comment: Wrong library? Watch again. https://youtu.be/xH8mpOfRGxE?t=291

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed. I found out that allegro libraries was not compatible with my linker. I've updated allegro libraries and it's working fine now.